# Why is the viewer window in R studio busy when I read in a data.frame?

Tags: r, rstudio

I started a new session in R Studio. When I read in a `data.frame` from a `.csv` file, the "Viewer" window is busy and does not stop. Does anyone know what the cause might be and more importantly, how to prevent it, please?

The environment is completely empty, I have no packages loaded and the only code I am using is:

```
 mydata <- read.table("~/Desktop/mydata.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", 
      check.names=FALSE)
```

Re-installing R Studio on my Mac did not help either.

I am unable to use R at all this way :(

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the libraries you're loading and the code you're using to load the csv? Otherwise I'm not sure this is really possible to diagnose.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. Please see edit above.

Comment: I found out that it is specific to the .csv file, because I am able to read in another .csv file. I'll investigate more to see what the problem might be. Thank you.

Comment: Is the CSV very wide, ie many columns? In some versions and some platforms that has led to RStudio sluggishness.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that. The file had 116 columns. I just found out that after removing a few columns (reduced to 105 columns total), it worked, so you could be right. On the other hand, I recently used a much larger file (~1000 columns) and there was no problem, so I am still not sure why. Sorry I cannot be more helpful and post exactly why this happened.